# image widthis less than the display width then how to set the image in total display width in codename one

Tags: image, width, codenameone

```
how to show the image in total width of the device when the image width is less than the device width?
```

image sizes :width - 1274 pixels,height - 105 pixels
device sizes:width - 1920 pixels,height - 1200 pixels

```
enter code here
Image image     = Image.createImage("/mainpageheader1.png");
Label appHeader = new Label(image);
appHeader.setUIID("appHeader");
loginForm.addComponent(BorderLayout.NORTH,appHeader);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Image.scaledWidth(int)](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Image.html#scaledWidth-int-) method to create a scaled version of your image with the desired width while preserving aspect ratio.